# How to save a textview's result into txt or pdf file on the internal storage of the device?

Tags: android, pdf

I'm new on android development and i plan to print my result of my calculation on my app through print API, and i will use txt or pdf file for this mission.

for every calculation there is an output which will be as a `textview` like that:

```
Result.setText(" Weight + i1+ \nHeight+i2");
```

the result may be reach 20 lines !!!
and first of all i need to save it as a txt or pdf file on the internal storage of the device  ?!

**So, if there is any way to do that please help.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have some other method for creating a String or byte[] containing your data. When you place them into internal storage, they're saved as raw bytes usually, and the extension name really doesn't mean much (but you can add one if you want).

```
    //create an output stream
    FileOutputStream out = null;

    try {
        //open output to internal storage. filename here is whatever 
        //you want to use to call it (extensions are optional)
        // context can be application or activity context
        out = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        //data is your string or byte block or whatever
        out.write(data);

    //catch all exceptions
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```